# java codes for a restaurant multiple steps

Tags: java

**Question 1:**

Assuming “OOP Restaurant” owner has engaged you to write a Java
program to take the restaurant customer order. The beverage menu of
the restaurant is as shown in Table 1. This program must allow customer
to decide how many items he/she wish to order. Then, it will let the
customer to choose the each item according to his/her preference. Upon
completion of the ordering, the program will display the total amount of
the order to the customer. Then, the program must ask the customer
whether to do another set of ordering.

In your code, you must create a method to process the item choice and
return the price of the item using the following method signature:

```
double processItem(int input)
```

The sample out is as shown in Figure 1.

```
Beverage     | Price
Fried Rice   | RM5.50
Chicken Rice | RM5.00
Toast Bread  | RM2.00
Mixed Rice   | RM3.80
Table 1
```

How do i even start this? i'm a law student but got forced to do this please do help me out your kindness would be repayed thanks in advance

Comment: give me your paypal =)

Comment: You could start with [The Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) and the [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/scanning.html) class.  May people use it to process user input from the console.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a 'do my howework'-service, if you have a real and specific problem, ask it.

Comment: i wish i could but i'm a law student and they forced us to do an assignment like this , i know it's not do my homework but atleast i would try to understand if i have the basic's

Comment: *"Question 1:"*  No, that is a specification.  [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)  I mean *besides* asking us.  *"i wish i could but i'm a law student.."*  And you think that is relevant to getting an answer by SO?  That is a (pathetic) excuse.

Comment: i have no idea where to even start... i was hoping for some pointer's

Comment: maybe try a site like rentacoder?

Comment: *"i was hoping for some pointer's"*  Start with your text books, go on to your class notes & hand outs, then proceed to [Getting Started](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/index.html).

Comment: As a law student you may find a loophole to squeeze yourself out of the situation.

Comment: @AndrewThompson it might be an excuse to you but right now i just need pointers and where to start and was that word pathetic really necessary? if you don't want to/cannot help its fine stay off and please act more matured because i know you are

Comment: Start learning what a `Class` is. What different classes you need to create. How to make `method calls` on `objects`. Here you go: http://thenewboston.org/list.php?cat=31

Comment: *"was that word pathetic really necessary"*  It seemed to have the right effect so ..yes, I think it was effective communication.

Comment: The problem here is that what you're asking us to do is (a) teach you java from scratch (since you havent told us where your problem is), or (b) write it for you. You must understand how neither of those things are going to happen, law student or not. Break it down into individual problems (getting user input in, storing data, outputting) and solve each one individually. If you find problems with any element then search for it, if you cant find your answer then ask the *specific question* here

Answer (score 3):

Having written the answer out this is quite a complex task for a non-programmer.  There's concepts of how a program should be structured to contend with after which comes the compilation and running.

This answer is in just that order, first I'll explain what I think the key points are (sure I've missed some, as much of this is second nature) then I'll give you pointers on how to run the code.

Step 1.

Think about what's involved if you were going to do this on paper - you'd have a list of beverages each with a name and a price (the menu).  An order comprises of one or more beverages from the menu in varying quantities.  You multiple the price of each beverage by the quantity to get the cost of the order.

Step 2.

Modern computer languages use a technique call Object Orientation, which in a nutshell involves describing the entities in general terms to create what is known as classes.  When presented with a problem, like that in step 1, a good rule of thumb in deciding what the classes should be is to look at the nouns - in this case beverage, menu and order look like good candidates.  A class typically has attributes (the data that will make instances unique) and behaviour (operations based on that data) though you'd don't neccessarily have to have both as you can see from the code below.

Step 3.

I imagine to a non-programmer, step 2 doesn't make much sense, so here's some code (which I hope makes it a bit clearer):

```
/**
 * This is the way classes are defined in Java, the public bit just says it's visible
 * to every other class in the system.
 */
public class Beverage
{
  //These are the attributes (fields) of the class.  It's good practice to make them
  //private so that they can only be accessed from within the class.
  private String name;
  private BigDecimal cost;

  /**
   * This is the constructor, which is used to create instances of the class.  In
   * this case it takes the arguments used to initialize the attributes of the class.
   */
  public Beverage(String name, BigDecimal cost)
  {
    this.name = name;
    this.cost = cost;
  }

  /**
   * This is a getter, which provides access to the attributes from outside of the  
   * class.
   */
  public BigDecimal getCost()
  { 
    return this.cost;
  }

  public String getName()
  { 
    return this.name;
  }
}

public class Order
{
  //This line is assigning an instance of HashMap (a standard data structure class 
  //in Java).  A map is a bit like a dictionary, you have a key in this case the
  //beverage that allows you to look-up another value, the quantity.
  private Map<Beverage, Integer> beverages = new HashMap<Beverage, Integer>();

  public BigDecimal getTotal()
  {
    BigDecimal total = BigDecimal.ZERO;

    //Loop over all the beverages that have been added to the map summing the cost.
    for (Beverage beverage : this.beverages.keySet())
    {
      //Convert the quantity in the map to a BigDecimal needed for the multiply method.
      BigDecimal quantity = new BigDecimal(this.beverages.get(beverage));

      total = total.add(beverage.getCost().multiple(quantity));  
    }

    return total;
  }

  public void add(Beverage beverage, Integer quantity)
  {        
    //Store the quantity against the beverage.
    this.beverages.put(beverage, quantity);  
  }
}
```

These two classes are all you need to solve the problem.  Menu is abscent because Java provides a class for a list of items.  Next you need to use them in a program.

Step 4.

In Java any class can be 'run' providing it has a special method called `main`.  Again, it's probably easier with an example:

```
public class Restaurant
{
  /**
   * The main method is static meaning it can be accessed without creating an instance
   * of the Restaurant class.
   */
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Map<String, Beverage> menu = new HashMap<String, Beverage>();

    //Create the instances of Beverage and add them to the menu.
    menu.put("Fried Rice", new Beverage("Fried Rice", new BigDecimal(5.50)));
    menu.put("Chicken Rice", new Beverage("Chicken Rice", new BigDecimal(5.00)));
    menu.put("Toast Bread", new Beverage("Toast Bread", new BigDecimal(2.00)));
    menu.put("Mixed Rice", new Beverage("Mixed Rice", new BigDecimal(3.80)));

    //Create an order and add items from the menu to it.
    Order order1 = new Order();
    order1.add(menu.get("Fried Rice"), 2);
    order1.add(menu.get("Toast Bread"), 3);
    order1.add(menu.get("Mixed Rice"), 1);

    System.out.println("Total for order 1: " + order1.getTotal()); 

    //Create another order and add items from the menu to it.
    Order order2 = new Order();
    order2.add(menu.get("Chicken Rice"), 1);
    order2.add(menu.get("Mixed Rice"), 1);
    order2.add(menu.get("Toast Bread"), 2);

    System.out.println("Total for order 2: " + order2.getTotal()); 
  }
}
```

Step 5.

That's all the code I think you'll need.  But in order to run it there's a few further steps.  First is to install the [Java Development Kit](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html), which can be download from Oracle.  Then, in Java, each class is typically declared in a text file that has the same name as the class with a `.java` extension - you'll end up with `Beverage.java`, `Order.java` and `Restaurant.java`.  Next you need to compile your program - in basic terms this is the process of verifying the code you have written and converting it to something the Java Runtime can understand.  I won't attempt to explain that, it's pretty well covered in the [Getting Started Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/cupojava/win32.html), which also explains how to run a Java program - ultimately you'll be looking for a command line that looks something like:

```
java -cp [path to class files] Restaurant
```

Comment: *"That's all the code I think you'll need"*  Not if this person becomes your co-worker.  I for one, sure hope that happens.